# Stopwatch Script using BASH

Tags: bash, date, stopwatch

This script initiates a stopwatch and takes 1 integer argument. The stopwatch will start at the specified time, in seconds( if args are given ), or from '0'( if no args are given ). However, if I pass arguments to this Script, it hinders the core functionality of the Script, i.e days are no longer updated.

```
if [ $1 ]
then
    date1=(`date +%s`+$1);
else
    date1=`date +%s`;
fi


while ! read -t0; do 
    days=$(( $(($(date +%s) - date1)) / 86400 ))
    echo -ne "$days day(s) and $(date -u --date @$((`date +%s` - $date1)) +%H:%M:%S)\r";
    sleep 0.1
done
```

It's important that I get the script to start from a certain time. I'm unable to get it to do so. Otherwise, the script works just fine without any arguments passed

Thank you.

Comment: ``date1=(`date +%s`+$1)`` is wrong: that is array syntax. You want `date1=$(($(date +%s) + $1))` or `date1=$(date -d "now + $1 seconds" +%s)`

Comment: Glenn Jackman, Thank you so much. Your suggestion solved the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd write your script like this, but I confess I don't understand the actual problem you're having with it. Please add more details to your question.

```
#!/bin/bash
start=$(date +%s)
if [[ $1 == ?([+-])+([0-9]) ]]; then
    ((start += $1))
elif [[ $1 ]]; then
    echo "invalid argument '$1': ignoring it"
fi

while true; do
    now=$(date +%s)
    days=$(( (now - start) / 86400 ))
    seconds=$(( (now - start) % 86400 ))
    printf "\r%d day(s) and %s " $days $(date --utc --date @$seconds +%T)
    sleep 0.1
done
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's the Final working Script. Thanks to Glenn Jackman.

```
# this script initiates a stopwatch
# this script can take 1 integer argument
# the stopwatch will start at the specified time, in seconds( if args are given ), or from '0'( if no args are given )
# Example : if you want the timer to start at 4 days, 5 hours, 33 minutes and 9 seconds, then you'd run the Script as :
# ./Stopwatch $((86400*4 + 3600*5 + 60*33 + 9 ))

if [ $1 ]
then
    date1=$(($(date +%s) - $1));
else
    date1=`date +%s`;
fi


while ! read -t0; do 
    days=$(( $(($(date +%s) - date1)) / 86400 ))
    echo -ne "$days day(s) and $(date -u --date @$((`date +%s` - $date1)) +%H:%M:%S)\r";
    sleep 0.1
done
```

Comment: Note that your example throws an error: `bash: 86400*4 + 3600*5 + 60*33 + 09: value too great for base (error token is "09")` -- bash treats numbers beginning with zero as octal, and "09" is an invalid octal number

Comment: I've modified the answer accordingly. Thanks.